# Trouble with overriding subclass in swift

Tags: swift

I'm having some trouble overriding a class in swift.  As per the directions from the class

> 1. Create a “Car” class with the following criteria:
>
>    - a.  Properties (5)
>    - year – initialized by initializer
>    - make – initialized by initializer
>    - model – initialized by initializer
>    - color – initialized by initializer
>    - currentSpeed – initialized to 0 by an initializer
>
> Create a subclass “Batmobile” that inherits from the Car class
>
> - Properties will remain unchanged
> - Functions
> - Override the init() function so that it only accepts year as input the rest of the attributes should be automatically initialized as
>     such:
>
>   - make – Bat Automotive
>   - model – Batmobile
>   - color – Black
>   - currentSpeed – 100

These are the class declarations I've created: 
Car:

```
class Car {
    //properties of cars
    var year : Int
    var make : String
    var model : String
    var color : String
    var currentSpeed : Int

    //functions of cars
    init(year : Int = 0, make : String, model : String , color : String , currentSpeed : Int = 0) {
        self.year = year
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.color = color
        self.currentSpeed = currentSpeed
    }
}
```

Batmobile:

```
class Batmobile : Car {
    override init(year: Int) {
        self.year = year
        self.make = "Bat Automotive"
        self.model = "Bat Mobile"
        self.color = "Black"
        self.currentSpeed = 100
    }
}
```

When I tried to create a Batmobile object with:

```
var myBatmobile = Batmobile(year: 2018)
```

I get the following error:

> Missing argument for parameter 'make' in call

I'm not sure what I should be passing into the Batmobile class in order for it to initialize properly.  I was under the impression that the override init function would replace all the inherited fields with the strings I supplied.

Comment: This is not the error you would get. Are you sharing the exact same code that you using?

Comment: With your code I am getting this error message: `Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass`

Comment: Sorry I just trimmed it down, here is the full source:

https://pastebin.com/vJf56E1q

Comment: That code different from what you posted. You would get an error for every parameter you missed. You are missing parameters. Edit the question with the real classes. Also, you are missing `super.init` in your subclass. Are you sure about the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like so:

```
class Batmobile : Car {
    init(year: Int) {
        super.init(year: year,
                   make: "Bat Automotive",
                   model: "Bat Mobile",
                   color: "Black",
                   currentSpeed: 100)
    }
}
```